# Install python modules on MAMP

Tags: python-2.7, oauth-2.0, pip, mamp

I am trying to install the oauth2 python module on MAMP but am not sure how to do it properly. I have tried using pip install but it installs the package in the root system and not in MAMP directory. Is there an easy way to do this? Thanks.